# How do I update a subfield of which I know everythig, but don't know the field its a child to?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have this collection:
{_id, list}

I have the elements in the list, of which each has an _id of its own, but I can't figure out how to update all the elements in the list. I do know that all collections have unique elements in the list, including amongst themselves. And I have the elements with updated properties :|

Hope I explained it clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I've got your problem right.

Suppose, you want to update given sub-document in the list by its `_id`, but you don't know its parent's `_id`.

To make an update operation you may use the following command:

```
db.collection.update({
  'list._id': subdoc_id
},{
  $set: {
    'list.$.field1': value1,
    'list.$.field2': value2,
    'list.$.field3': value3
  }
})
```

To replace an old sub-document with the new one (equivalent of `save`):

```
db.collection.update({
  'list._id': subdoc._id
},{
  $set: {
    'list.$': subdoc
  }
})
```

But you should be aware that this operation will completely erase the old sub-document and replace it with the new one. So, any field not listed in `subdoc` will be deleted.

`{'list._id': subdoc_id}` query will find you a parent document containing the given sub-document and `'list.$'` selector will point to the queried sub-document.

**Update:** If you don't know in wich particular list the given sub-document is stored, you'll need to run an update operation on each:

```
['list1', 'list2', 'nested.list'].forEach(function (list) {
  var query = {};
  query[list+'._id'] = subdoc._id;
  var update = { $set: {} };
  update.$set[list+'.$'] = subdoc;
  db.collection.update(query, update);
})
```

An update will be performed on each list where the given sub-document is present.

Comment: I don't know if its called "list". Should it be: $set: {
    '$.field1': value1 } ?

Comment: How do you expect to find it in the first place if you don't know where it stored?

Comment: I know its in one of the lists. Don't know which of them.

Comment: I will redo my mongodb structure. This might work but I won't go that way. ty

Comment: Why don't you want to store all your sub-documents in a separate collection? It'll solve your problem.

Comment: It is messy :| I'd have to get all the X _ids for the collections first, then make X updates, AND it will make X-1 operations for nothing AND I will have to wait for all X operations to end so I can call the complete handler. From all this I can tell I was doing it wrong.